# Will a transfer that has been cancelled mid way through have complete data up to that point?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, data-transfer

Hi I wanted to copy 2 very large folders containing many subfolder and files each to a USB memory stick.

I set this going but when I came to check back later it was only 60% complete. I decided I no longer wanted to wait for the rest so cancelled the transfer.

Upon looking at the contents of the stick one of the folders appears to have transferred in its entirety (as the folder has the same size and number of files in it as the original) and the second folder had only partial contents of the original.

I am assuming what happened is it transferred folder 1, then was part way through folder 2 when I cancelled the operation.

My question is this,

Will the first folder be fully complete with no errors, corruption etc. so can I just copy the remaining folder 2 in at a later date....

or will I have to clear the usb drive and start from the beginning of transferring both folders to ensure the integrity of the data transfer?

(Btw this is Windows 10 and a 128gb USB2.0 stick if it makes any difference)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the first folder be fully complete with no errors, corruption etc. so can I just copy the remaining folder 2 in at a later date.

A copy operation within Windows is per file.  If a copy operation for a specific file is started but aborted before it finishes then only the original will exist.

> will I have to clear the USB drive and start from the beginning of transferring both folders to ensure the integrity of the data transfer?

I would simply verify the files have actually been copied.

Answer (score 1):

The copy operation will be aborted as expediently as possible when you click Cancel. Windows will not take any action to finish copying the contents of the currently-copying directory (if it were large and the copy just entered it, completing the directory could mean the copy would need to run a few more hours!)